# mDNS Support for WebRTC at Google Chrome M74

Tags: webrtc, mdns, chrome-canary

Google Chrome scheduled for M74 release that the mDNS support for local ICE candidates will be involved in the browser to increase privacy. 
This feature is controlled by the feature flag *-enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns* ;

[image: chrome flag]

I am trying to test the effect of mDNS support for WebRTC users on Google Chrome. I am testing with my custom WebRTC App and execute below test steps before making call;

1- WebRTC clients are logged in with using identical mDNS broadcast domains,

2- mDNS in Google Chrome Canary is enabled via -enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns flag on both party,

After the call has been generated, I saw that WebRTC agents are replaced their private IP's with anonymous local IP's which are followed by ".local";

[image: mDNS IPs]

Also I detect that the call signaling is generated and the media stream is performed successfully, but the ICE candidates are chosen from relay candidates(used TURN Server), not host candidates;

[image: webrtc internals]

I think the parties cannot resolve their anonymous IP's and select to establish communication on existing TURN Server (use relay candidates).

I am sure that the clients are under the same subnet, but why they cannot resolve each other's anonymous IPs? I know that the nodes are broadcasted their anonymous IPs via 5353 port of mDNS and I expected that they will resolve the IPs easily. Is there anything that I missed during testing?

Your assistance would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: this looks like you might have UDP blocked -- there are no srflx candidates and the relay candidates seem to be TURN/TLS (candidate priority of 7935 >> 24 is 0)

Comment: also there seem to have been issues in Chrome, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=937992#c3

Comment: Hi @PhilippHancke, thanks for the direction. I think that would be a bug. I used Chrome Canary to test during the error scenario. Then I tried it with chrome M73 and the call is successfully established via host candidates. Then I tried it to understand why Canary exposed the use relay, but it also established successfully and I am sure I did not change anything for configuration. I suspected that the caches of both peers are updated during the success path of Google Chrome M73, and then Canary use these cached values to resolve IP's.