# JavaScript detection of LAN IP address

Tags: javascript, ip, lan

I have been using the following code to detect the LAN IP address of a client running some proprietary software (please no "you shouldn't do this", I didn't write the code).

```
function ip_local()
{
 var ip = false;
 window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || false;

 if (window.RTCPeerConnection)
 {
  ip = [];
  var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]}), noop = function(){};
  pc.createDataChannel('');
  pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);

  pc.onicecandidate = function(event)
  {
   if (event && event.candidate && event.candidate.candidate)
   {
    var s = event.candidate.candidate.split('\n');
    ip.push(s[0].split(' ')[4]);
   }
  }
 }

 return ip;
}
ip_local();
```

Which is from another StackOverflow post, the code has been working fine for a year and a half up until this afternoon.

Where as my local ip seems to be detected as 153b3a68-e3fb-4451-9717-d9b3bc2b5c60.local instead of the usual 192.168.0.11.

Edit: 
If anyone cares, this issue is NOT bypassable and has to be done via a server side language, in my case I ended up using PHP as a temporary "bandaid" over the problem.

This is a problem for my app as it detects whether a local server is running on the host.. Which it cannot do if it cannot detect the LAN IP address.

Comment: Why don't you post a comment in the other SO question, asking why it's not working any more?

Comment: Because this seems limited to my experience. It's not an "across the board" kinda deal. I wondered if anyone else has any experience with this.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked.

Comment: This is my point, I was wondering if anyone else has had my experience, as my per question.

Comment: It looks like you have a local DNS server that's performing a reverse DNS translation of the IP to a name.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local

Comment: this is currently an experiment but rolling out in Chrome 75. You are using WebRTC for a purpose that its not designed for and that is often abused.
If you think you haver a legitimate use-case, acquiring camera permissions with getUserMedia will give you IP addresses.

Comment: @PhilippHancke - Ahh a possible fix! I'm definitely using it as it was supposed to be used. That is to detect the IP to connect to a newly run server on the localhost. But perhaps this getUserMedia will work :/ What a nightmare....

Comment: I wouldn't bank on that working for very long.  It's incredibly short sighted, in my opinion, of browser developers to assume that people are only using WebRTC for voice and video chat.  I suspect this mistake will be fixed.

Comment: I ended up using a server side language as per my edit. @Brad

Comment: Use this method if you have mac: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543917/unable-to-fetch-ip-v4-address-from-rtcpeerconnection-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of a new security standard, to prevent leakage of private IP addresses.

See also:  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-mdns-ice-candidates-02

Summary:

> As detailed in [IPHandling], exposing client private IP addresses by
> default maximizes the probability of successfully creating direct
> peer-to-peer connection between two clients, but creates a
> significant surface for user fingerprinting.  [IPHandling] recognizes
> this issue, but also admits that there is no current solution to this
> problem; implementations that choose to use Mode 3 to address the
> privacy concerns often suffer from failing or suboptimal connections
> in WebRTC applications.  This is particularly an issue on unmanaged
> networks, typically homes or small offices, where NAT loopback may
> not be supported.

> This document proposes an overall solution to this problem by
> registering ephemeral mDNS names for each local private IP address,
> and then providing those names, rather than the IP addresses, to the
> web application when it gathers ICE candidates.  WebRTC
> implementations resolve these names to IP addresses and perform ICE
> processing as usual, but the actual IP addresses are not exposed to
> the web application.

Comment: Ouch, so there is no way around it? This is part of Windows now?

Comment: @BarrieReader No, there's no way around it, and nor should there be.  If this is capability you need, use a browser extension.  This is part of Chrome (and probably other browsers), not Windows.

Comment: A browser extension isn't possible as the app runs in Chrome's AppMode... And it runs locally... So trusting individual users to install the extension is a no-go :(